# Will adding 'match_about_blank' trigger a permission warning?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I work on a chrome extension that injects content scripts into all frames on all webpages. I'd like to extend this functionality by adding `"match_about_blank": true` to the content script permissions in the manifest file. In the [chrome extension docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permission_warnings#update_permissions), it says that updating an extension with additional permissions may temporarily disable it. My question is, will adding the match_about_blank attribute to a content script trigger this permission warning?

Comment: It doesn't change which sites are affected so there should be no warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close the loop here- the comment by wOxxOm above is indeed correct. I posed this question on the chromium forum and received a full detailed response from a chromium dev here: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-extensions/AnWzbP76ZZs

For anybody else who arrives here wondering if a permission change will cause their extension to be disabled when they push an update, if you follow the instructions here https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permission_warnings#update_permissions you can actually test this locally (pack and install current build of extension, then make changes and pack and install the extension again using the same private key).